# CNTK ImageDeserializer and DCGAN sample

Tags: cntk, dcgan

I'm reworking this sample  https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Tutorials/CNTK_206B_DCGAN.ipynb to work with png MNIST files (rather than flat 1d array image input that tutorial uses). I use ImageDeserializer (and map file to load the data):

```
def create_mb_source(map_file, image_dims, num_classes, randomize=True):
transforms = [
    xforms.scale(width=image_dims[2], height=image_dims[1], channels=image_dims[0], interpolations='linear')]
return MinibatchSource(ImageDeserializer(map_file, StreamDefs(
    features=StreamDef(field='image', transforms=transforms),
    labels=StreamDef(field='label', shape=num_classes))),
                       randomize=randomize)
```

I changed the input output of  to Discriminator to expect 28x28 image (and output of Generator). See the code here: https://github.com/olgaliak/cntk-cyclegan/blob/master/trainDCGan.py

the problem is that trainDCGan.py is generating noise now. Appreciate your  help!

Comment: Would it be possible for you to verify the data coming out in the minibatch sample is correctly shaped and renders the digits image as per your expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue got solved once I
1)  Switched to used 3 channels in ImageDeserializer
2)  Changed network architecture to use 2d strides\kernels instead 1d.
[This commit](https://github.com/olgaliak/cntk-cyclegan/commit/ad9fe3211cff53509523e8ed67c34f40f9b6898b#diff-f16dd2f802015fd8ecc910b627aaa315) highlights the changes that made things working.